# Increase height and width of date and time fields

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

I have been making an app using the following stacks:
`Reactjs`, `Typescript`, `TailwindCSS`, `Chakra UI`

Now, I am using an input of type `datetime-local` and I might want to use the app on a touchscreen monitor so for that the date and time sizes are very small. See the image below for example

[image: Date Time Screenshot]

For now, my code looks like this:

```
<Input
type="datetime-local"
className="mb-3"
/>
```

Is there any way we can increase the size of the dates? If not then what can we do about this?

I didn't find anything over stack overflow regarding this. Please point me in the right direction

Comment: I think you have to find another way to handle **mobile datetime picker**.
You just can custom these things https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/e7ad60a5304c2196e0123dcd7cee0804f7f317b1/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css#L1294-L1322